# Time derivative of the absolute value of a vector dependent on time.

Tags: vectors, derivatives

We consider: $$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{|\vec{x}(t)|}$$ where $\vec{x}(t)$ is a 3 dimensional vector.

I assumed I should apply the total derivative: 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{|\vec{x}(t)|} = -x_1(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\frac{dx_1}{dt} -x_2(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\frac{dx_2}{dt} -x_3(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\frac{dx_3}{dt}$$

Is my assumption and computation correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Comment: Also note that the whole thing can be written a bit more compactly as
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{1}{|\vec{x}|} = - \frac{1}{|\vec{x}|^3} \left(\vec{x} \cdot \frac{d \vec{x}}{dt} \right).
$$

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this question?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is correct and could be simplified as$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{|\vec{x}(t)|} =$$

$$ -x_1(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\frac{dx_1}{dt} -x_2(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\frac{dx_2}{dt} -x_3(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\frac{dx_3}{dt}=$$

$$-(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}} (x_1\frac{dx_1}{dt}+x_2\frac{dx_2}{dt}+x_3\frac{dx_3}{dt})=$$

$$- \frac{1}{|\vec{x}|^3} \left(\vec{x} \cdot \frac{d \vec{x}}{dt} \right).$$